# android intent extra data retrieval problem

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, extras

I have a wierd problem. I have the following code:

```
if (fbIntent.hasExtra("Link")) {
            try{
            postData[0]= fbIntent.getStringExtra("Link");
            } catch (Exception e) {Log.d("fbIntent error",e.getMessage() );} 
        }
```

fbIntent.hasExtra("Link") is true. So the compiler goes into the if statement. But I am not able to get the string using fbIntent.getStringExtra("Link"). This I know from debugging in eclipse. When I run it, I get :

```
01-21 14:12:01.030: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(311): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.examples.Kikin/com.examples.Kikin.FacebookLogin}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
```

Please help me.

Comment: You did initialize postData, right?

Comment: yeah. I did. though I did it as null. Does it matter?

Comment: Need to see more of the code. Also, the stack trace should tell you what line exactly the NPE is occuring on.

Comment: I changes the initialization to arbitrary values. Now it seems to be working. could you tell me why is this?

Comment: You need to be more specific. "The initialization"? "Arbitrary values"? Can you post code of what you're referring to?

Comment: String [] postData={"http://www.kikin.com","Brian","Interesting Info"};  This is what I initialized to rather than null.

Comment: Well yeah, when postData is null, postData[0] will crash. You'd need to at least say `String[] postData = new String[1]`.

Comment: oh. ok. sorry. i thought you could do it like that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize postData. Try something like `String[] postData = new String[1]`. Obviously, if you want use postData[1], [2], and [3], you'd need to say `new String[4]`.

Answer (score 0):

1) Your current issue is in

```
Log.d("fbIntent error", e.getMessage());
```

`e.getMessage()` may return `null`, so you get the `java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message`. Use `e.toString()` instead. Or the best way would be:

```
Log.e("some tag", "some comment", e);
```

2) When you fix this, you will be able to see the actual error to go further in fixing your root/real issue. So feel free to update your post with new log data.

Comment: That was not my issue. Thank you for the information though. I changed all my getMessage() to toString().